# Extract data for different points from Sentinel-1 at once using earth engine

Tags: javascript, time-series, google-earth-engine, sentinel1

I am trying to extract sentinel-1 time series data for different locations from earth engine. The locations in this case are not present in single sentinel-1 image, but are distributed in several images. Following is the code I have tried. However, I am not able to do it properly. Please guide me in this regard.

```
// Define the locations you want to retrieve data for
var locations = [
  ee.Geometry.Point([-120.1331, 39.3272]), // Location 1
  ee.Geometry.Point([-121.9730, 37.3280]), // Location 2
  ee.Geometry.Point([-118.4085, 33.9416]), // Location 3
];
// Create an ee.FeatureCollection object from the locations array
var locationsFC = ee.FeatureCollection(locations.map(function(location) {
  return ee.Feature(location);
}));

var pointStyle = {
  color: 'FF0000',  // red
  fillColor: 'FF0000',
  pointSize: 8
};


// Add the ee.FeatureCollection object to the map
Map.addLayer(locationsFC.style(pointStyle), {}, 'My Shapefile');

// Define the time range you want to retrieve data for

var startDate = '2023-01-01';
var endDate = '2023-01-20';

// Load Sentinel-1 SAR data
var sentinel1 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
  .filterBounds(ee.Geometry.MultiPoint(locations))
  .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
  .select(['VV']);

print(sentinel1);

// Define the target projection as WGS84
var wgs84 = ee.Projection('EPSG:4326');

// Define a function to reproject an image to WGS84
function reprojectToWGS84(image) {
  var reprojected = image.reproject({
    crs: wgs84,
    scale: 10 // set the scale to use for the reprojection
  });
  return reprojected;
}

// Apply the function to the sentinel1 image collection
var sentinel1_wgs84 = sentinel1.map(reprojectToWGS84);

print(sentinel1_wgs84);

// Define the scale at which to sample the image
var scale = 10;

// Define a function to sample the image at the points
function sampleImage(image) {
  return image.select(['VV']).sampleRegions({
    collection: locationsFC,
    scale: scale,
    tileScale: 16
  });
}

// Define the export file name
var fileName = 'sentinel1_vv_data';

// Select the VV band from the image collection
var vv = sentinel1_wgs84.select('VV');

// Sample the VV data at the point locations
var sampledData = vv.sampleRegions({
  collection: locationsFC,
  scale: scale
});

// Export the sampled data as a CSV file
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: sampledData,
  description: fileName,
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
});
```